# "export 'MatTableModule' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use  but getting "export 'MatTableModule' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

My github repo:
https://github.com/Combii/dates-reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing

npm install --save @angular/cdk

And had only installed @angular/material

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to import from material table

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
```

Comment: I'm already doing that in my app.module.ts

Comment: firstly `MatTableModule` is not available in `@angular/cdk/table` can you please elaborate what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I wish to have the same table from https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: The example they have called Basic use of `<mat-table>` (uses display flex). I've copied their source code and imported in app.module.ts but get the error ("export 'MatTableModule' was not found in '@angular/cdk/table') when I run my app

Comment: can you share me the link of the example? I guess it should be a miss on their side

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ymolaolqxnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-flex-example.ts

Comment: @David in that example, please see this line `import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';` in #39 in `material.module.ts` file it is imported from `material/table`

Comment: Hi again, I solved it look at my answer below.